# How to refer the text nearby a checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose there are multiple couple of checkbox and its text  -

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /> <input class="num" type="text" /><br />
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /> <input class="num" type="text" /><br />
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /> <input class="num" type="text" /><br />
```

What is the most elegant way to refer the text for just whose its `checkbox` is `checked` ?

**Edit:** more description for what I want

Select all the numbers in the text whose its `checkbox` is `checked` and then calculate the sum of those numbers  .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but perhaps you could use a framework such as [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

`input:checked + input[type=text]`

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yAL4p/1/

EDIT: since you need summation:

```
function updateSum() {
   var sum = 0;
   $('input:checked + input[type=text]').each(function() {
      //If it's an invalid number, return and go to the next element.
      var value = $(this).val();
      if(!isNaN(value)) return;

      //*1 here so that it doesn't concat the string but instead treat it as integer
      sum += value*1; 
   });

   //Do whatever you want with sum here
}

//Update the sum everytime a checkbox change is invoked
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(updateSum);
```

Fiddle for EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/yAL4p/7/

Comment: This is a very smart solution. Downside is this will fail horribly when the html is changed, and they're no longer nexto eachother

Comment: @Martijn I'm just following the requirement in the title "nearby a checkbox" and by looking at the HTML, I assume nearby is next. Which is why I don't try to do it for general cases.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you want with them, so this might not be very usefull, but it explains the concept:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).next()[0].value;
    if( !isNaN(value) ){ sum+= parseInt(value,10); } // only add if its a number
})
```

In more complex code this might not work. Or when you change your code, this will fail (if the input is no longer the next item). To fix that, you can wrap each line, In this example the `div`:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).parent().find('.num')[0].value;
    if( !isNaN(value) ){ sum+= parseInt(value,10); } // only add if its a number
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="text"]')
```

Comment: You just copied the contents of my and SiGanteng's replies.

Comment: I dont know what happend, but im absolutely sure your answer editted, and rolled back. BUt I dont see a 'last edit', so removed the downvote :)

Comment: I just remove another option to do this with .next() method only. But didn't copy.

Comment: And typically there is obvious difference from your code.